# Finding indices of mismatched curly brackets in a string

Tags: python, stack

I have a program that takes a variable string e.g: "John walked to {{Location} at {{Time}}"

I need find the unmatched curly brackets and remove them and the string inside. I understand that a stack can be used to detect unmatched brackets but how do I track the indices so that I can remove any variables that have unmatched brackets along with the brackets itself?

Comment: You would have to be more specific on what rule you want to apply to determine where you expect the missing bracket should be, or which one to consider an extra.  There are multiple possibilities even in you simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use accumulate (from itertools) to compute bracket nesting levels at each character position in the string.  When there is a mismatch, the levels will go under 0 at some point (going forward or backward).  The negative levels will identify potential mismatches but you'll still need to analyze them to determine what range of characters they are supposed to be covering:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def badBrackets(S):
    deltas   = [(c=='{')-(c=='}') for c in S] # 1 or -1 for open/close
    forward  = [*accumulate(deltas,lambda a,b:max(0,a)+b)]        # forward levels
    backward = [*accumulate(deltas[::-1],lambda a,b:min(0,a)+b)]  # backward levels
    levels   = [min(f,-b) for f,b in zip(forward,backward[::-1])] # combined levels
    return [i for i,b in enumerate(levels) if b<0]                # mismatches
```

output:

```
S = "John walked to {}}}{{Location} at {{Time}}"

print(badBrackets(S))

[17, 18, 19]
```

positions 17 and 18 are mismatched closing brackets so they should pertain to something on the left (but how far to the left ?)

position 19 is a mismatched opening bracket, does it correspond to a missing closing bracket after `{Location}` or a missing closer at the end of the string that would include `{Location} at {{Time}}` ?